# IMAP - retrieve mail by Yahoo X-YMailISG

Tags: email, imap, yahoo, mime, yahoo-mail

Appears for all incoming Yahoo mail, X-YMailISG is an incoming message ID mail can be retrieved by.  I'm wondering if this is possible in IMAP or if this field is used for something else entirely?

Comment: @Max - yes, a custom one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4), section 6.4.4, you could use `SEARCH` or `UID SEARCH` with the `HEADER` qualifier to look look for the identifier for that message.

Quoted:

```
HEADER <field-name> <string>
         Messages that have a header with the specified field-name (as
         defined in [RFC-2822]) and that contains the specified string
         in the text of the header (what comes after the colon).  If the
         string to search is zero-length, this matches all messages that
         have a header line with the specified field-name regardless of
         the contents.
```